# Why is the displayCounts crashing my app?

Tags: java, android

I can't understand why the displayCounts keeps crashing my app..... It says I'm calling a virtual method on a null object.... Can someone help me please?

Basically it updates a counter everytime one of it's methods has been run but everytime I add in the displayCounts bit it crashes.

```html
package course.labs.activitylab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

 // Use these as keys when you're saving state between reconfigurations
 private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
 private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
 private static final String START_KEY = "start";
 private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

 // String for LogCat documentation
 private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityOne";

 // Lifecycle counters

 // TODO:
  private  int mCreate = 0;
    private  int mRestart = 0;
    private int mResume = 0;
    private int mStart = 0;


    private TextView mTvCreate;
    private TextView mTvRestart;
    private TextView mTvStart;
    private TextView mTvResume;

 // Create variables named
 // mCreate, mRestart, mStart and mResume
 // to count calls to onCreate(), onRestart(), onStart() and
 // onResume(). These variables should not be defined as static.

 // You will need to increment these variables' values when their
 // corresponding lifecycle methods get called.

 // TODO: Create variables for each of the TextViews
 // named mTvCreate, mTvRestart, mTvStart, mTvResume.
 // for displaying the current count of each counter variable

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

  // TODO: Assign the appropriate TextViews to the TextView variables
        mTvCreate = (TextView)  findViewById(mCreate);
        mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(mRestart);
        mTvStart = (TextView)  findViewById(mStart);
        mTvResume = (TextView)   findViewById(mResume);

  // Hint: Access the TextView by calling Activity's findViewById()
  // textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

  Button launchActivityTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchActivityTwo);
  launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {



    // Launch Activity Two
    // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method

    // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to
    // start
               Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Launch the Activity using the intent

   }
  });

  // Has previous state been saved?
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {

   // TODO:
            mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
            mStart =savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
            mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
            mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);

   // Restore value of counters from saved state
   // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable

  }

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onCreate() method");

  // TODO:
        mCreate++;
       //displayCounts();
  // Update the appropriate count variable
  // Update the user interface via the displayCounts() method

 }

 // Lifecycle callback overrides

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStart() method");

  // TODO:
        mStart++;
        //displayCounts();
  // Update the appropriate count variable
  // Update the user interface

 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onResume() method");

  // TODO:
        mResume++;
        //displayCounts();
  // Update the appropriate count variable
  // Update the user interface

 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onPause() methodc");
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStop() method");
 }

 @Override
 public void onRestart() {
  super.onRestart();

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onRestart() method");

  // TODO:
        mRestart++;
        //displayCounts();
  // Update the appropriate count variable
  // Update the user interface

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onDestroy() method");
 }

 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO:
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
  // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs
  // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable

 }

 // Updates the displayed counters
 // This method expects that the counters and TextView variables use the
 // names
 // specified above
 public void displayCounts() {

  mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
  mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);
  mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);
  mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);

 }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure all the variables you set in the textView are not null? Did you check them using a System.out or a Log?

Comment: I could not undertsand the way you declared textviews in your code `mTvCreate = (TextView)  findViewById(mCreate);` could you explian why this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreate, you are assigning the mTvCreate, mTvStart, etc. views to findViewById(0) which is commented as TODO in your member variable declarations. Assign IDs to these views in your activity_one.xml file that you are inflating and pass these into findViewById. Then you should be getting the proper view references instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like code from the Coursera class that's running right now. You've got to reference the IDs in the layout file when calling findViewById(); Will be in the format "R.id.create".

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have to write:

```
mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create); 
mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restart); 
mTvResume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resume); 
mTvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
```